# How to split and scale streams in ffmpeg with cuda?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nvidia

So, I want to create streams of multiple resolutions for hls streaming. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -i input.mkv -c:a aac -c:v h264_nvenc \
-c:s webvtt -crf 20 -filter_complex \
'[v:0]hwupload_cuda,split=2[vtemp001][vout002]:[vtemp001]hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=w=960:h=540:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload,format=yuv420p[vout001]'  \
-map "[vout001]" -b:v:0 2000k -map "[vout002]" \
-b:v:1 6000k -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -map 0:v \ 
-map 0:a -map 0:s -var_stream_map 'v:0,a:0,s:0 v:1,a:1,s:1' \ 
-force_key_frames:v "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2.000)" -hls_time 6 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_flags \
delete_segments+independent_segments+discont_start+program_date_time \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_segment_filename \
fire/segment_%v/file%06d.ts fire/stream_%v.m3u8
```

Running this, I am getting the following error:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 
'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

When I do the same thing without gpu, I am getting an out of memory error which to me sounds like I can't do this without a gpu (i.e I have to run separate ffmpeg commands to get this to run on the CPU). Would love to know if anyone has any insights or suggestions.

I tried something more easy to understand here:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -i input.mkv -c:v h264_nvenc -filter_complex \
'[v:0]hwupload_cuda,split=2[vtemp001][vout002];[vtemp001]hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=w=960:h=540:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload,format=yuv420p[vout001]' \
-map "[vout001]" -b:v:0 2000k output1.mkv -map "[vout002]" -b:v:1 6000k output2.mkv
```

The above gives the same error which to me suggests that the issue is with the filter complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ended up working for me

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mkv -c:a aac -c:v h264_nvenc -c:s webvtt -crf 20 \
-vf hwupload_cuda,yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,scale_npp=w=960:h=540:interp_algo=linear \
    -b:v 2000k -force_key_frames:v "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2.000)" -hls_time 6 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_flags \
    delete_segments+independent_segments+discont_start+program_date_time \
    -hls_segment_filename out/file_960_%06d.ts out/stream960.m3u8 \
-vf scale=w=1280:h=720 \
    -b:v 2800k -force_key_frames:v "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2.000)" -hls_time 6 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_flags \
    delete_segments+independent_segments+discont_start+program_date_time \
    -hls_segment_filename out/file_1280_%06d.ts out/stream1280.m3u8
```